# Rebooting caused "mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock"

Tags: ubuntu, mount, disk

I have a backup drive on `/dev/sda1` but after doing a simple `apt-get upgrade` and rebooting my server I can no longer mount it.

**mount /dev/sda1 /backups**

```
mount: /backups: special device /dev/sda1 does not exist.
```

When I setup the server I did `mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda1` and the drive has been working completely fine for many weeks until I rebooted just now.

This is the output of lsblk and fsck:

**lsblk**

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda           8:0    0   3.7T  0 disk
nvme0n1     259:0    0 419.2G  0 disk
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   511M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0   511M  0 part
│ └─md2       9:2    0   511M  0 raid1 /boot
├─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0 417.7G  0 part
│ └─md3       9:3    0 417.7G  0 raid1 /
└─nvme0n1p4 259:4    0   511M  0 part  [SWAP]
nvme1n1     259:5    0 419.2G  0 disk
├─nvme1n1p1 259:6    0   511M  0 part
├─nvme1n1p2 259:7    0   511M  0 part
│ └─md2       9:2    0   511M  0 raid1 /boot
├─nvme1n1p3 259:8    0 417.7G  0 part
│ └─md3       9:3    0 417.7G  0 raid1 /
└─nvme1n1p4 259:9    0   511M  0 part  [SWAP]
```

**fsck /dev/sda1**

```
fsck from util-linux 2.31.1
e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
fsck.ext2: No such file or directory while trying to open /dev/sda1
Possibly non-existent device?
```

**fsck /dev/sda**

```
fsck from util-linux 2.31.1
e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
fsck.ext2: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
fsck.ext2: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sda

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>

Found a PMBR partition table in /dev/sda
```

**The current contents of `/etc/fstab`**

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>                         
/dev/md3        /       ext4    errors=remount-ro       0       1
/dev/md2        /boot   ext4    errors=remount-ro       0       1
/dev/nvme0n1p4  swap    swap    defaults        0       0        
/dev/nvme1n1p4  swap    swap    defaults        0       0        
proc            /proc   proc    defaults                0       0
sysfs           /sys    sysfs   defaults                0       0
UUID=4497-A8EC  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults        0       0
```

I tried adding

```
/dev/sda1        /backups   ext4    errors=remount-ro       0       1
```

To `/etc/fstab` but that only caused the server to be unable to boot.

**fdisk -l /dev/sda**

```
Disk /dev/sda: 3.7 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sda1           1 4294967295 4294967295   2T ee GPT
```

**cat /proc/partitions**

```
major minor  #blocks  name

 259        0  439548984 nvme0n1
 259        1     523264 nvme0n1p1
 259        2     523264 nvme0n1p2
 259        3  437971968 nvme0n1p3
 259        4     523264 nvme0n1p4
   9        2     523200 md2
   9        3  437971904 md3
 259        5  439548984 nvme1n1
 259        6     523264 nvme1n1p1
 259        7     523264 nvme1n1p2
 259        8  437971968 nvme1n1p3
 259        9     523264 nvme1n1p4
   8        0 3907018584 sda
```

**testdisk /log /dev/sda**
https://pastebin.com/raw/mUHfDubj

Does anyone know what could have happened and how to fix the drive?

Comment: fsck /dev/sda is not good- might have wrecked your superblock, fsck /dev/sda1 would be correct. AFAICS your system doesn't recognize the partition.

Comment: @stoney I tried `fsck /dev/sda1` first. I added the output of that above. I haven't tried repairing anything yet.

Comment: I *really* hope that your hard drive was not 206 degrees Celsius!

Comment: Add the output of `parted /dev/sda print free` or `fdisk -l /dev/sda` and the one of `cat /proc/partitions` to your question.

Comment: Added those @HaukeLaging

Answer (score 2):

Your `fdisk` output indicates the disk used to have a GPT partition table at some point. The partition of type `ee` is just a dummy that tells operating systems that only understand MBR "there is something going on here that you won't be able to understand, please don't touch". For GPT-aware operating systems, it means "the GPT partition table is the real one, please read it instead."

The GPT partition table lives at the beginning of the disk just after the classic MBR one, and there is supposed to be a backup copy of the GPT partition table at the very end of the disk. The fact that the system fails to recognize it suggests that both copies may have been damaged, or that your kernel fails to identify the correct one for some reason.

You might use `testdisk` (should be available as a package in Ubuntu) to scan for partitions and hopefully recover them. Please install it if necessary, and then run:

```
sudo testdisk /log /dev/sda
```

Select partition table type `EFI GPT` and start a quick search. With a 3.7 TiB disk, even a "quick" search might take a while. If the filesystem is still present on the disk, this tool should detect it, determine its beginning and end locations, and rebuild a valid partition table entry for it.

The tool will not overwrite anything without displaying its findings first. Then it will give you a chance to see if the results look valid or not, and if you're sure they are valid, you can choose to write a corrected partition table to the disk. But if you are uncertain, the `/log` option tells it to create a log file, which you could then post somewhere and add a link to it into your question for further details.

Comment: Added the log to the question

Comment: How do I figure out which partition to select?

Answer (score -4):

You might check under `/dev` if there is still an `sda1` entry. If not you can create one.

```
cd /dev
ls -l sda*
```

Edit: NVM, as mknod does not resolve the deeper issue of why /dev/sda1 is not created by the kernel.

I will leave this answer up, as it is linked to elsewhere.

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: Your answer currently reads more like a comment. Fleshing it out with an example would be helpful.

Comment: And how would you create it?

Comment: This is a troubleshooting situation, so I know it's not quite correct to put the suggestion as the answer, since it's not known yet. I'd rather have posted it as a clarifying question to your post, but I don't have the needed 50 reputation points. If you'd like, I will delete my answer in order to attract other suggestions.

Comment: The main problem with your answer is not that you do not even mention `mknod` but that it does not make a difference if `/dev/sda1` exists. `lsblk` does not need that file. That device file is created if the kernel detects an `sda1` partition, not the other way round.

Comment: But mount does need it, so if it is somehow not there, the mount will fail, probably with that message. Certainly worth checking. One could certainly add information on mknod -if needed.